# How to make a weekly calendar with events

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I'm trying to make a calendar like this [Fullcalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poLv6.jpg) but all the calendars that I can find online are showing the whole month. I already made a [calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc2pu.jpg) but i don't know how to put the events under the right day. The calendar needs to be a full week because I want to have multiple calendar underneath each other for multiple people.

Comment: you need at least to show us some code so we can try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the code on this site https://www.phpzag.com/create-event-calendar-with-jquery-php-and-mysql/#

Comment: **Do not follow phpzag.com tutorials!** They are advocating bad programming practices and their code samples are full of security problems. Please learn about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) first.